# What is the equivalent of "cat /dev/nvram > backup.cmos" in Windows?

Tags: bios, cmos

On some Linux systems, it is possible to dump BIOS CMOS raw data using `cat /dev/nvram > backup.cmos`. What is the equivalent of this command on Windows?

Comment: There isn't one with built in tools (probably). You'd have to look for specialized tools for that. As you're already saying it's not even available on every Linux machine.